# Frequency of resigning in won positions

Tags: blunder, resigning

The most terrible blunder is to resign in a won position.

How can I systematically search for such games ?

How often does this happen if both opponents have, lets say, at least ELO 2400 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a comprehensive list on Tim Krabbé's page [The Ultimate Blunder](http://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/resigntxt.htm).